# Forgotten account password

Tags: windows-server-2008, password-recovery

I kept my passwords recorded but the location on my PC where I kept this went missing. I now can't get into Windows Server 2008 R2 as I can't remember the administrator or named account credentials and have no password reset disk. This is on a VM (VM Player - which btw is temp till I get Hyper-V).

How can I get back in? If I make AD can I join the server to AD and then set a domain account?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [How-To-Geek's Tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-forgotten-windows-password-with-the-linux-system-rescue-cd/) on how to do exactly what you want. **Note:** This will require a using a LiveCD (Linux) but trust me it's very easy.

Comment: I will try this. One question - does the fact that I am using a VM change anything?

Comment: The fact that it's a VM doesn't make much difference.  Rather than create a physical CD and boot from that you'll just mount the ISO from within VMware and boot from that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know an administrative account to join an Active Directory.

There are a number of free password reset bootable disks available.  I've used several for years with no trouble but none on 2k8.  I don't know if they will work or not so you will want to seek other opinions.

Comment: The default setting is that any user account can join a PC to an AD Domain. But this still wont get him an Admin account in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try Hiren CD.. This will surely work..

www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd